# Spring scope=`prototype`: how to change all bean instances?

Tags: java, spring, singleton, prototype, design-patterns

I've a simple class which perform some check agains list of Regex patterns. My patterns are set somehow with constant list of values. This is not a question as for now, so I'm omitting that setting code.

```
class Checker {
   private final Pattern [] patterns = new Pattern[10];

   public boolean check(final String param){
     for(Pattern p : patterns){
        if(p.matcher(param).matches())
           return true;
      }
     return false;
   }
}
```

Stuff is failry simple.
Now I'm accessing that class from 500 simultaenous threads. Class is created with default Spring scope `singleton`.

Making access to `patterns` synchronous:

```
class Checker {
   private final Pattern [] patterns = new Pattern[10];

   public boolean check(final String param){
     synchronized(patterns){
      for(Pattern p : patterns){
         if(p.matcher(param).matches())
            return true;
      }
     return false;
     }
   }
}
```

Well, since all threads access single instance of my class - they gets locked within synchronized block. Since my class is fairly lightweight I'd like to create separate instance for each thread (e.g. change scope from `singleton` to `prototype`). Removing synchronization block and adding `getInstance` factory method backed by `ThreadLocal`. Like that:

```
class Checker {
   private final Pattern [] patterns = new Pattern[10];

   public boolean check(final String param){
     for(Pattern p : patterns){
        if(p.matcher(param).matches())
           return true;
      }
     return false;
   }

   private static final ThreadLocal<Checker> checkerLocal =
      new ThreadLocal<Checker>() {
       @Override 
       protected Checker initialValue() {
         System.out.println("Creating Checker instance")
         return new Checker();
       }
   };

   public static Checker getInstance(){
          return checkerLocal.get();  
   }
}
```

Works like a charm.

However, imagine that I've to **dynamically** modify patterns somehow inside my application (e.g. add or remove Pattern there). I should perform that for all existing instances of `Checker` class.
I'm thinking on using `ApplicationContext#getBeansOfType(Checker.class)` method to get all bean instances. But is there any other more `springy` way to do so?

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to accomplish. Is `check` `synchronized` so that any changes to `patterns` will be visible? If so, won't using a prototype bean defeat the purpose? `Pattern` objects are thread-safe, so it seems like it would make more sense to simply use a thread-safe collection and remove the synchronization on `check`.

Comment: Yeah. My question was how to modify `patterns` on all instances of `prototype` bean dynamically ;)

Comment: Still not understanding why you made `check` `synchronized` in the first place.

Comment: Coz it's `singleton` and `patterns` could by dynamically changed from different threads simultaenously. Although `Pattern` is thread-safe, array of `Pattern` is not.

Comment: It seems to me that what you need is for the `Pattern`s to be provided by a Spring bean. Have you considered a singleton-scope holder (`PatternService`) that returns `synchronizedList` (or Guava `ImmutableList`) and uses `AtomicReference` and a `synchronized` block on that bean for updates? Your `Checker` bean would call `getPatterns()` on each invocation to get a reference to the most current list of patterns, and you wouldn't have any synchronization overhead on just reading the most recent valid copy of the patterns.

Comment: In that case I'll need synchronized block for traversal `for(Patter p: patterns)` also. Otherwise I'll get `ConcurrentModificationException` if one thread changes the list while I'm traversing on it. And that sycnrhonized block don't make me happy at all. My idea is to hold lists in each Checker instance and don't rely on synchronization.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42212/discussion-between-archer-and-chrylis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my suggestion. The `Checker` class doesn't have to have any synchronization at all, since it only ever pulls an unmodifiable `List<Pattern>` out of the holder class, and the only synchronization needed is to prevent clashing updates on the holder.

```
public class PatternService {
    AtomicReference<List<Pattern>> patterns = new AtomicReference<>(Collections.emptyList());

    public List<Pattern> getPatterns() {
        return patterns.get();
    }

    public synchronized void addPattern(Pattern p) {
        List<Pattern> newPatterns = new LinkedList<>(patterns.get());
        newPatterns.add(p);
        patterns.set(Collections.unmodifiableList(newPatterns)); // or ImmutableList
    }

    // other mutators
}


public class Checker {
    @Autowired PatternService patternService;

    public boolean check(String param) {
        for(Pattern p: patternService.getPatterns())
            if(p.matcher(param).matches())
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll try your suggestion now.